Domain admin can't display effective permissions for a folder
I need to display effective permissions for one person in one shared folder, but I get a message saying I don't have permissions to evaluate it. I am a Domain Admin, owner of the folder, have full control over it. What more permissions do I need? Why am I unable to evaluate permissions for this user, who is not any kind of admin, just a regular domain user? The exact message is:

You do not have permission to evaluate effective access rights for the remote resource. Contact the administrator of the target server.

